# will setting up android BackupAgentHelper ensure that my app will get installed upon factory data restore

Tags: android, android-backup-service

I've set up backup / restore in my application via BackupAgentHelper per instructions in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html

I was also hoping that when I do factory reset on phone B, my application will get installed there, but that's not the case.  I have not deployed my changes to play store, i am testing it by installing APK via adb to various devices.

I think my AndroidManifest.xml is configured correctly

```
<application
    ...
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:backupAgent="com.gilt.android.MyAppBackupAgent"
    ...
>
```

What could I be missing?  Does my code need to be deployed to play store for this backup / restore to register properly?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the answer is APK with BackupAgentHelper needs to be deployed to play store.  Once I deployed APK to app store, our application started restoring itself on factory reset devices.